# How do I make the Expo Camera View Clickable

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am using the Expo Camera in React Native. I want to snap a picture when the Camera view is tapped. How do I do this?

I have tried putting the TouchableOpacity inside the camera tag but when i try to log to console when the user taps the camera view nothing happens

```
<Camera style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%', display: this.state.camera }} type={this.state.type} autoFocus={'on'} ratio={'4:3'}   focusDepth={0} ref={(ref) => { this.camera = ref }}>
<TouchableOpacity style={{width:'100%', height:'100%'}} onPress={()=>console.log("Testing cam")}>

</TouchableOpacity>
</Camera>
```

I want it to print the "Testing Cam" in the console when i tap on the Camera View

Comment: I dont know much of `react-native` but based on their documentation it says that Camera should be inside TouchableOpacity

Comment: Alright I’ll try that

Comment: Wow it worked, you might as well put it as an answer

Comment: just added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put `Camera` inside `TouchableOpacity`, and not other way around:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{width:'100%', height:'100%'}} onPress={()=>console.log("Testing cam")}>
    <Camera style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%', display: this.state.camera }} type={this.state.type} autoFocus={'on'} ratio={'4:3'}   focusDepth={0} ref={(ref) => { this.camera = ref }}>
    </Camera
</TouchableOpacity>
```